# How to multiply $x$ by $2(x + 3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm getting stuck with a part of an exercise that I do not understand: I know how to use the distributive property with $2(x + 3)$, but I have to multiply $x$ by $2(x + 3)$, and I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: multiply $2x$ by $x$ and $3$ individually. The answer is: $ 2x^2+6x$.

Comment: Thanks you for all your answers, I bet that this question could be very simple for someone with  a good knowledge in maths, but it's quite hard for my level (high school)

Comment: i didn't mean it that way. I apologize.

Comment: There's no problem, I understand the meaning of your answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $2(x+3)=2x+6.$ So:

$$x\cdot (2(x+3))=x\cdot (2x+6)=x\cdot 2x+x\cdot 6=2x^2+6x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the distributive property. $$2(x+3) = 2x + 6$$ and then $$x(2x+6) = 2x^2 + 6x$$

Answer (score 0):

To multiply x by 2(x + 3), use the distributive property
$$ 2x(x+3) = 2x^2+6x$$
Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

$x\cdot(2(x+3))=2x(x+3)=2x^2+6x$